# ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cannot be converted to List<List<Integer>>

Tags: java

I'm doing a problem on leetcode: given a list of integers, return a list of lists that contains all the possible permutation of these numbers. The class and method are the following:

```
class Solution {
    public List<List<Integer>> permute(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> permu = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        more code here ...
        }
    }
```

The compiler threw an error `"ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> cannot be converted to List<List<Integer>>".` I know that the return type must be `List<List<Integer>>` instead of `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`, but I can't declare `List<List<Integer>> permu = new List<List<Integer>>();` because list is an interface. How should I declare permu correctly, if I'm not allowed to change the return type in the permute method?

Comment: `List<List<Integer>> permu = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();` or `new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: Does `... = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();` work?

Comment: In this example `List<Dog>` would be new `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` and `List<Animal>` would be `new ArrayList<List<Integer>>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it like this:

```java
List<List<Integer>> permu = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

Or even

```java
List<List<Integer>> permu = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
List<List<Integer>> permu = new ArrayList<>();
```

This should work since it can implicitly understand what types should be there.